# Slow Query with Dynamic WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know the query below is not the best, but right now it has to do the job:

```
FROM dbo.CE_Summons_ext0 s with (nolock)
     INNER JOIN dbo.CE_Fines_ext0 f with (nolock)
       ON (f.ref_no = s.ref_no AND f.doc_type = s.doc_type)
     INNER JOIN dbo.CE_charge_status c with (nolock)
       ON f.status = c.status_no
     INNER JOIN dbo.CE_COURT_DESC crt_desc with (nolock)
       ON crt_desc.COURT = s.COURT
     INNER JOIN dbo.CE_CntParms_ext0 param with (nolock)
       ON param.REF_NO = s.ref_no
     INNER JOIN dbo.CE_Court_result crt_result with (nolock)
       ON crt_result.COURT_RESULT = param.COURT_RESULT
  WHERE   s.SUMMONS_NO = isnull(nullif(@sms_summons_no, ''), s.SUMMONS_NO)
      AND s.ref_no = isnull(nullif(@scp_ref_no,''), s.ref_no)
      AND s.COURT =  isnull(nullif(@sms_court,'') , s.COURT)
      -- AND f.STREET1 = isnull(nullif(@street1,''), f.STREET1) 
      -- AND f.acc_name = isnull(nullif(@offender_name,''), f.acc_name)
      -- AND f.id_no = isnull(nullif(@offender_id,''), f.id_no)
      -- AND f.acc_name = isnull(nullif(@owner_name,''), f.acc_name)
      -- AND f.id_no = isnull(nullif(@owner_id,''), f.id_no)
  END
```

On the `WHERE` clause if I uncomment the last conditions it runs horribly slow.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `NOLOCK` on *every single join*?

Answer (score 3):

This looks as if you are determining the where clause based on the values of parameters. The most effective way to do this in terms of performance is usually to build the query dynamically using dynamic SQL so that you do not have to use functions in the where clause.

Comment: Agreed, you also open yourself up to a myriad of parameter sniffing issues with what you have. If you had an actual value for each `nullif(@param,'')` it should/would run much faster. OP, do you know how to build out the query using dynamic SQL and run with `sp_executeSQL`?

Comment: Dynamic SQL > [link 1](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/), [link 2](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing with this:

```
(@Street1 IS NULL OR @Street1 = '' OR f.STREET1 = @Street1)
```

Comment: Eliminate one part of teh or clasue by limiting the variables to either null or "" or converting the '' to null outside the query.

Comment: @HLGEM Agreed, that would make it better.  I was just suggesting improvements with the query as is.

Answer (score 2):

When you're executing the query (in both cases) go to the Query menu in SSMS and select Include Actual Execution Plan. That will tell you the specific parts of the query that are slow and why.

I realize this isn't a direct answer to your question, but it is a very useful means by which you can research and solve your own issue as well as learn how to better diagnose slow queries.